# Bootstrap Responsive Image size

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3. 
I am adding an image (Logo) and want it responsive. So the natural state is 100% width. I want it to stay the same relative size to the Text next to it in different browser widths. Is this possible or do you have to adjust size with more breakpoints? In other words say from lg to md I can get the right size and position but if the monitor they have is over the breakpoint at 1200px like 1400px the image or logo ends up way to large but the text flows right in the row next to it and in tablet size the med width I can get it set right for the breakpoint but if someone has a 50px smaller size screen than an iPad then it will look to big. Any suggestions?

Edit:How do you copy and paste the code in if yo have to indent it all four spaces? Makes it very hard to add the code. I am not going to rewrite it all. I pasted it in and it wouldn't allow me to indent most of the lines. So thanks for the effort but I will work this out on my own.

Comment: share your code, what have you done so far.

Comment: Thought it would not be needed for such general question

Comment: <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
      <h1 class="text-center">#</h1>
    </div>
    <img src="RFA_circles.png" alt="Logo" width="150" height="150" class="img-responsive col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3
     col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3
     col-md-2 col-md-offset-0  col-lg-2">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
       <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

Comment: Trying to add the code but it won't let me maybe tomorrow.